# Find and print all indices of the minimum value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers and I want to print all indices at which the minimum value can be found.

My Attempt:

```
myList = [3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2]

minValue = min(my_list)

my_list.count(minValue)

if mylist.count(minValue) > 1:
    for num in mylist:
        if num == minValue :
            print(my_list.index(minValue))
```

Actual Result:

```
1
1
1
```

Expected Result:

```
1
4
7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use 

`for idx, num in enumerate(myList): if num == minValue: print(idx)`

Comment: `index(minValue)` will always give you the first index that matches minValue

Answer (score 3):

Careful that your list has the same name everywhere, I fixed this for you in my example. Your problem can be solved by using enumerate() in your for loop.

```
my_list = [3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2]

minValue = min(my_list)

my_list.count(minValue)

if my_list.count(minValue) > 1:
    for i, num in enumerate(my_list):
        if num == minValue :
            print(i)
```

Your problem was printing `my_list.index(minValue)`, which always returns the first instance of the minValue, so the solution is to print the current index that the for loop is at for every item matching minValue.

Answer (score 2):

`.index()` returns index of the first occurrence of the element passed to it. You can use `enumerate`.

```
>>> my_list = [3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2]
>>> min_val=min(my_list)
>>> for idx,val in enumerate(my_list):
        if val==min_val:
            print(idx)
```

Using `range`.

```
>>> my_list=[3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2]
>>> min_val=min(my_list)
>>> for i in range(len(my_list)):
    if my_list[i]==min_val:
        print(i)        
1
4
7
```

As suggest in comments by [Corentin Limier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4289380/corentin-limier). You should use `enumerate` over `range`. [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150762/pythonic-range-vs-enumerate-in-python-for-loop?lq=1).

The above can be written as ***list comprehension*** if you want to store the indices of the `min` value.

```
min_val=min(my_list)
min_indices=[idx for idx,val in enumerate(my_list) if val==min_val]
print(*min_indices,sep='\n')
```

---

output

```
1
4
7
```

Here's a `numpy` approach.

```
import numpy as np

my_list=np.array([3, 2, 5, 7, 2, 4, 3, 2])
x=np.where(my_list==my_list.min())
print(x)
print(*x[0],sep='\n')
```

---

output

```
(array([1, 4, 7], dtype=int64),)
1
4
7
```

Comment: Why you should use enumerate over range https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150762/pythonic-range-vs-enumerate-in-python-for-loop?lq=1

Comment: @CorentinLimier Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @CorentinLimier Thanks for taking out your time in improving the answer. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about using numpy?

```
np.argwhere(np.array(my_list)==min_value)
```