# Can we use lambda function to reduce the following function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like to ask if the below function could be reduced by using 1 expression with lambda function. I am trying to locate the indices of the price list to see if there is an increase in prices from the previous index

```
def increasePrice (prices):
   templist = []
   for x in range (0, len(prices)):
      if (prices [x] < prices [x+1]):
      templist.append(x)
   return templist
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of the `if` statement.

Comment: reduce is not a good word choice ... shorten ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Yeah, I thought the question was about the `reduce()` function.

Comment: Your code will get an error on the last iteration, since `prices[x+1]` will be out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your code is missing an indentation (after if), missing `)`, and iterates over the full length of `prices`, which results in IndexError, since you index `prices[x+1]` which doesn't exist at the last index. If you fix those, the below list comprehension produces the same outcome.

You could use `enumerate` to get the indices along with `zip` to iterate over consecutive elements in a list comprehension:

```
templist = [x for (x, p1), p2 in zip(enumerate(prices), prices[1:]) if p1 < p2]
```

You can also enumerate over the zip (thanks @Barmar):

```
templist = [x for x, (p1, p2) in enumerate(zip(prices, prices[1:])) if p1 < p2]
```

Comment: It's just a style difference, but I would use `enumerate(zip(...))` rather than `zip(enumerate(...), ...)`

Comment: The nesting `x, (p1, p2)` seems more natural.

Comment: Actually, `i for i in range (0, len(prices) - 1) if prices [i] < prices [i+1]` works as well right?

Comment: @PythonLearner indeed it does; however, using `enumerate` when getting the index is the pythonic way (since `enumerate` is precisely made for this). Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150762/pythonic-range-vs-enumerate-in-python-for-loop) too.