# How to stop programs printing out in alphabetical order

Tags: python, list, output

So, I'm working on a program which converts input text into Discords regional_indicator emoticons but the issue is that if a word is entered such as "cab" the output will return as "abc". Is there any way of changing the program so that when words are entered, they aren't sorted into alphabetical order. (I've only programmed the first 3 letters for testing purposes. Coded in Python IDLE 3.5)

```
import sys
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
sentenceLower = sentence.lower()
sentenceList = list(sentenceLower)
sentenceListLength = len(sentenceList)
while sentenceListLength > 0:
    if "a" in sentence:
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_a:")
        sentenceListLength = sentenceListLength - 1
    if "b" in sentence:
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_b:")
        sentenceListLength = sentenceListLength - 1
    if "c" in sentence:
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_c:")
        sentenceListLength = sentenceListLength - 1
```

In short, the program receives a sentence, checks if letters appear in that sentence and then it prints out text to be copy and pasted into Discord.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but I think you probably want to iterate over the characters in the sentence instead of looking for characters in the sentence.

Comment: This is a less efficient way of doing it than the least efficient way I could come up with in my head on short notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through the characters in the sentence rather than looping through the number of characters.

```
for c in sentence:
    if c == "a":
       sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_a:")
    elif c == "b":
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_b:")
    elif c == "c":
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_c:")
```

What you are doing is just checking if there exists a character in the string, so it will give you the letters back out of order.

Comment: I like how you answered the exact question but did not address the aesthetics and inefficiency of the multiple `if`. +1

Comment: You did at least switch to `elif` though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was the issue. I feel kinda stupid for completely forgetting about elif statements xD

Answer (score 1):

One way is

```
import sys
sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
sentenceLower = sentence.lower()
sentenceListLength = len(sentenceLower)
for i in range(sentenceListLength) :
    c = sentenceLower[i]
    if ( ("a" <= c) and (c <= "z") ) :
        sys.stdout.write(":regional_indicator_"+c+":")
    else :
        # Do your stuff
        pass
```

You could as well traverse characters with

```
for c in sentenceLower :
```

instead of

```
for i in range(sentenceListLength) :
    c = sentenceLower[i]
```

(and it would be usually regarded as more pythonic). Using an integer index is sometimes more flexible/versatile (it is up to your case).

Comment: Even when an index is needed, it is usually obtained through enumerate instead of a range.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - It's largely a matter of taste. Speed is also a (minor) issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901081/only-index-needed-enumerate-or-xrange and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990105/rangelenlist-or-enumeratelist, e.g.

Comment: Seems like enumerate is a tad faster than calling `__getitem__` every time.